# three.js 3d model not showing in java project

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d-model

I have a `three.js` sample project which contains a 3d model. The main part of the project is in HTML file. If you run that HTML file, it works fine. The 3d model is in `.BDF` format.

Now I need to run this on a Java project (includes .java, .js and many other files). I replaced a HTML file which is already in the Java project with this HTML file (`three.js` project HTML). The file is calling correctly (HTML file is calling from a.js file), but the 3d model is not showing over the screen. (only the comments written in the body part of the HTML file is showing).

Note: I have included all the supporting files along with the HTML file.

Comment: Are you sure the model is imported correctly? Maybe try a sample of the Three.js website first, to check if it works at all. And then try importing the model.

Comment: Yes.. Actually I have included the complete three.js project folder into java project. So nothing to change there. And I am calling the .html script of the three.js project.